# How to change Bootstrap server address in generated Kaa SDK

Tags: sdk, bootstrap-modal, kaa

I generated SDK for my application in Kaa. Application worked correctly. After that I changed Bootstrap server host address and as I understand, I need to regenerate SDK in order to use new Bootstrap server address. This works, but is there a way to change Bootstrap server address in generated SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the Control service embeds a list of available Bootstrap services into the SDK (using a properties file for Java implementation, a header file for C++, etc.) during the SDK generation, and the SDK doesn't provide an API to override that list, so you can't change it.

Currently, if you need to change the Bootstrap server host - you need to regenerate the SDK.

For production, we recommend that you use DNS names that map to IP addresses of concrete nodes running the Bootstrap services so this will allow to manage Bootstrap servers IP addresses and help to avoid SDK regeneration.

Comment: still cant change Bootstrap server address in generated SDK?

Answer (score 0):

change the line to your host as follows:
transport_public_interface=YOUR_HOST
in the /etc/kaa-node/conf/kaa-node.properties file if you are running on linux.
You should restart kaa-node service and regenerate client sdk after you change the property file.